# Derivation of univariate normal distribution and how it approximates binomial distribution problems

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Can some one kindly explain the derivation of normal distribution (univariate) and how it could be approximated for binomial distribution (coin flip problem)? I have searched for hours but could not find any online.

I would like to know how to arrive at below formula and how it helps solve binomial distribution problem:
$f(x) = \dfrac {1}{\sigma \surd{2 \pi}}\text{exp}\Big( \dfrac {1}{2}(\dfrac {x-\mu}{\sigma}\Big)\Big)$

I am at a simple binomial distribution problem:
${\displaystyle P(X=k)={n \choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}}$

Comment: What do you mean by a "proof" of a distribution?

Comment: Derivation of f(x) noted above and how it first for binomial distribution. I have updated now accordingly. Its clearer now?

Comment: Yes.  You wish to know why the normal is a reasonable approximation to a binomial (under certain conditions).

Comment: and also how to arrive at that formula f(x) if possible in context of binomial distribution problem itself

Comment: [De Moivre-Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem)

Comment: but how np becomes variance in our binomial distribution problem @RobertIsrael

Comment: $np$ is the expected value.  The variance is $np(1-p)$.

Comment: how in context of binomial distribution?

Comment: @PaariVendhan  the link contains the precise proof with all details.

Comment: I am sorry I could not find, they start with np(1-p) as variance so unable to link with binomial problem (even though they have a gif on RHS with same problem). And why $\dfrac {k}{n} \rightarrow p$ is also not clear? I am already reading that link

Comment: [This](https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats1/x13.pdf) link seem to have an explanation (page 6) for var np(1-p), I will try to link the dots and revert if still any blocking in understanding. Btw, kindly clarify if possible why $ \dfrac {k}{n} \rightarrow p $ as if k is the mean?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Can you please clarify why \dfrac {k}{n} \rightarrow p in above proof?

Comment: The Law of Large Numbers shows that with high probability $X/n$ is near $p$.

Comment: According to [LLN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), they only say, sample mean approaches population mean, when no of samples sufficiently increase? That is $\sum$ in numerator, not just X or k like we have in $\frac {k}{n} \rightarrow p$

Comment: It has been over half a year now. Would you consider posting an answer and accept it yourself, or deleting this question post to wrap it up? I assume you have already got your solution here or elsewhere and moved on.

Comment: I have not gotten the answer, I wish it could stay so some one could answer. I have moved on to other topics, but this still remains unclear. Is it prohibited for a question to wait beyond 6 months in SO? any limit?